# sending data continuously to a subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, inter-process-communicat

I am testing the communication with a subprocess. I have to start a server, sending periodically data. The final target is a process that acquires meteo data and a plotting server. The sampling rate is of the order or minutes .... I wrote the these two fragments of code to understand the basics of ipc in python, but I am not even able to make them working.
The syncronism is not an issue.

main process

```
import sys, time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

print 'starting'
proc = Popen (['python.exe',
    'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\sub.py'], 
                stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)
print 'launched'

w = 0
while True:
    w += 1 
    time.sleep (2)
    print 'writing', w
    proc.stdin.write (repr(w))
    proc.stdin.flush()
    print proc.stdout.read()
```

subprocess:

```
import sys, time

print 'reading'
v = 0
while True:
    v = sys.stdin.read()
    sys.stdout.write('ACK')
    sys.stdout.flush ()
    time.sleep (4)
```

The main process is blocking, apparently the sub is not reading-sending the ACK.
where am I wrong ??? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `sys.stdin.read()` blocks, as it is trying to read the *entire* stream, thus it can't return until the stream is closed.

Try using `sys.stdin.readline()` and add a newline when writing using `sys.stdout.write()` (in both processes), e.g. `sys.stdout.write('ACK\n')`.  This should make sure the reading commands will block only until a single line is read.

Comment: great ! It works. It was my first post on the forum, really useful. Thanks

Comment: Yes, SO is the best. When you find an answer helpful, feel free to upvote or accept it.